# Take a list of names and randomly pair them off (SQL)

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to do something I thought would be fairly easy and am now on the verge of bashing my head off the desk!

I have a list of names as an array and I want to create random pairs from that list.

So I have

```
  SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        ('Angie'),
        ('Bob'),
        ('Meg'),
        ('Colin'),
        ('Debbie'),
        ('Eddie'),
        ('Fiona'),
        ('Gary'),
        ('Harriet'),
        ('Ian'),
        ('Julie'),
        ('Kevin'),
        ('Mary'),
        ('Noah'),
        ('Olivia')
) AS t (name)enter code here
```

and I want to get back something like

```
   Name 1  Name2

1. Olivia Debbie
2. Gary   Harriet
3. Bob    Mary
4. Noah   Colin
5. Ian    Fiona
6. Kevin  Mary
7. Julie  Eddie
8. Angie  NULL
```

Is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: Are you able to create tables at will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`row_number()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#row_number) and aggregation:

```
select max(case when mod(seqnum, 2) = 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when mod(seqnum, 2) = 0 then name end) as name2       
from (select name, row_number() over (order by random()) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor(seqnum / 2);
```

Comment: Hey Martin,

This is amazing and does _almost_ exactly what I want it to do. It randomly pairs everyone and leaves the odd one paired with null. However, if I add a 16th name to the list, it pairs all but 2 and those each end up paired with null. 

I don't understand the code well enough to see why it's doing that. 

Of course, if there are an even number of names then I'd like it to pair everyone ... and if there's an odd number then pair all but 1. Is there a way to change that?

Really useful though, thanks very much for that!

Comment: @BarryEvans . . . That is an off-by-one error, solved by "adding" `- 1` to the calculation for `seqnum`.  Who is "Martin"?

Comment: Apologies, Gordon. No idea where I seen 'Martin' :/

Comment: That is indeed the answer by the way. Thank you very much for all your help. Much appreciated!